# Httpd + /bin/false == system() ?

Tags: php, security, lighttpd

I have two web-servers, both on Lighttpd + php (through fastCGI).

```
[user@box ~]$ lighttpd -v
lighttpd/1.4.29 (ssl) - a light and fast webserver
Build-Date: Aug  7 2011 10:52:01
[user@box ~]$ php -v
PHP 5.3.8 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Sep 30 2011 05:34:36) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2011 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2011 Zend Technologies
[user@box ~]$ php-cgi -v
PHP 5.3.8 with Suhosin-Patch (cgi-fcgi) (built: Sep 30 2011 05:35:14)
Copyright (c) 1997-2011 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2011 Zend Technologies
```

Lighttpd and php-cgi are running under user 'http' with **/bin/false** (bogus) shell:

```
[user@box ~]$ cat /etc/passwd | grep http
http:x:33:33:http:/srv/http:/bin/false
[user@box ~]$ ps aux | grep "lighttpd\_php-cgi"
http      1291  0.0  1.1   5152  2816 tty1     S    Oct06   0:00 /usr/sbin/lighttpd -D -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf
http      1292  0.0  1.5  14476  3904 ?        Ss   Oct06   0:00 /usr/bin/php-cgi
```

But I still can execute shell commands through php's **system()** function (for example)!

There are no disable_functions in my php.ini.
If I execute **system("whoami")** or **system("id")** through php, I get the following:

```
http
uid=33(http) gid=33(http) groups=33(http)
```

(just as it must be).

What's the reason that I can execute commands from the user with **/bin/false** as shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explicitely said in the [documentation](http://php.net/system), php's `system` is just a binding for the system in C. From the [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system) of system:

> system() executes a command specified in command by calling `/bin/sh -c command` ...

`/bin/false` is just the login shell (used in conjunction with `login`, telnet, ssh, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

**/bin/false** has nothing to do here. You can't control access to system commands by changing a user's shell, because they are simply NOT executed via shell. Read more [here](http://www.semicomplete.com/articles/ssh-security/).

Comment: Oh, didn't knew that. Thanks, I will remember!